# Local alternative to backblaze

Tags: backup

After a disk crash of 3 disks at once, I need a better backup strategy. In principle, [Backblaze](https://www.backblaze.com/) would be the right thing for me, but my data volume and my DSL bandwidth just don't match. Since I handle large files (VMs) frequently, syncing via DSL would simply take too long.

Therefore I am looking for a local solution that works similar.

The software must

- sync files from my PCs to the server
- client runs on Windows 7 x64 and Windows 10 x64
- server could be OS (Ubuntu knowledge is available), but should be easy to administrate
- server supports RAID 1 mirroring
- file system support for disks of 8+ TB

Once set up, the client should not ask any questions, so my children and my wife can simply continue working without any interruptions.

Comment: If you plan to crash disks 3 at a time, you'll need more than RAID 0 :) More seriously, mirroring is RAID 1, and for large disks you may want RAID 6 (that's the one I use for a 16 TB NAS).

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: if I have RAID mirroring in my PC (2 disks) and RAID mirroring (2 disks) on the NAS side, that's 4 disks in total. Hopefully this will be sufficient. And I have learned to buy disks from different vendors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your own home network, it keep it simple - your backup system dosen't need to be aware of what its talking to.

I'd set up a ubuntu server to taste and consider two possible options.

[Bitorrent sync](https://www.getsync.com/) is a good option if 'you don't even want to think about it'. Set it up on both ends, [optionally disable its ability](http://sync-help.bittorrent.com/customer/portal/articles/1732504-can-i-force-sync-to-do-local-network-lan-syncing-only-and-not-sync-via-the-internet-) to connect outside a lan.

I went with a samba share (or three. I like redundancy) and a application that does file syncing. I went with [bvckup2](https://bvckup2.com/) - its not free but I've run it since the betas and its fairly competent, fast and reliable. You could swap it out for a free alternative, but I'd like to leave that as an exercise for you.

Both alternatives should work great on any platform. Btsync is *polished* and runs on everything under the sun. Samba + bvckup gives me a little more flexibility since I do local backups to a second drive as well.

Comment: bvckup2 is great. Bought 5 licenses.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest that you check out CloudBerry Backup to automate Windows Computer backup to Amazon S3 and Glacier and local storage such as the server as you suggested. It comes with the following features:

1. Scheduling and Real-Time Cloud Backup Comes with one time fee and no
   recurring charges.
2. No proprietary data format and you can access
   your data using other Amazon s3 tools.
3. Supports all Amazon S3 regions and Reduced Redundancy Storage and Standard-IA.
4. Amazon Glacier support
5. Encryption & Compression
6. **Local Backup**
7. Incremental and Block Level Backup
8. Network Locations Backup

[15 day free trial is available](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/backup)

Disclaimer: I work for CloudBerry Lab

Comment: Price info: for >1TB storage it requires the Enterprise Edition for ~300 USD